# Фильтр по модели с ManyToMany

Tags: python, django

Всем привет

У меня есть типичная модель с ManyToMany:

```
class Dialogue(models.Model):
    Partakers = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='dialogs')
```

И, например, у меня есть диалог между двумя Profile. Мне надо его выбрать через get. То есть мне нужно что-то наподобие:

```
Dialogue.objects.get(Partakers=[recipient,self.request.user])
```

Но так это не работает: django в ошибках пишет, что может обработать только строку или число, но не список.

И самое простое, что пришло в голову- это

```
Dialogue.objects.filter(Partakers__id=recipient_id).get(Partakers=self.request.user)
```

Такая выборка выберет все диалоги, в которых участвуют эти собеседники. И пока такой диалог один, все работает. Но если сделаю другой диалог, например, с тремя участниками, в котором будут участвовать эти двое, то такой запрос вернет и его тоже, **что мне совершенно не нужно**. А как обыграть эту ситуацию не знаю.

Пробовал `Partakers__in` - так этот вообще возвращает все диалоги, в которых эти ребята засветились. То есть вообще мимо.

И еще не пойму, почему возвращает пустоту

```
dialog = self.request.user.dialogs.filter(Partakers=recipient)
```

Результирующий запрос такой:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "main_dialogue" INNER JOIN "main_dialogue_Partakers" ON ("main_dialogue"."id" = "main_dialogue_Partakers"."dialogue_id") WHERE ("main_dialogue_Partakers"."profile_id" = '20' AND "main_dialogue_Partakers"."profile_id" = '7') LIMIT 21
```

Но такой куерисет всегда пустой

Comment: Не уверен, что это правильно. Но, как вариант, можно сделать условие на проверку количества участников в диалоге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим что у вас есть список профилей которые участвуют в диалоге, например как и вашем примере пусть это будет:

```
partakers = [recipient, self.request.user]
```

В первую очередь фильтруем по количеству участников диалога:

```
dialogs = Dialogue.objects.annotate(cnt=Count('Partakers')).filter(cnt=len(partakers))
```

Полученный `queryset` итеративно фильтруем по каждому участнику диалога.

```
for partaker in partakers:
    dialogs = dialogs.filter(Partakers=partaker)
```

В результате `dialogs` будет содержать `queryset` содержащий только диалоги для профилей из списка.